# Executing a command prompt from the web browser (safely)

Tags: git, browser, command, clone

I'd just like to know how to git clone a file onto a user's desktop when they click a button.

Is it possible? If it is, what measures can I take to prevent any input and or meddling from the user?

I really, really do not someone to hack their way in there and cause people to rm -rf / their computer.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no dear god please no. There is absolutely positively no secure way to allow a website to arbitrarily execute binaries/terminal scripts on the client machine.

Comment: Right on. Any way to accomplish this via an API or something?

Comment: Aside from potentially having the user download an application, I don't think so. Perhaps your best bet would be to use GH's approach of dynamically generating shell scripts and displaying them neat-and-tidy and ready-to-copy on the webpage for the user to copy/paste into terminal themselves? Sounds like it would only be a 1 or 2 line script.

Comment: That can be done. Do you think this will ever be a good idea or is the premise just too consequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While giving access to the command line from the browser is generally impossible/restricted, you still can trigger a git repo clone from a browser.

See:

- [BitBucket Web UI, and its "Clone with SourceTree" button](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/clone-a-repository-into-sourcetree-780870050.html#ClonearepositoryintoSourceTree-Method#2-ThroughtheRemoteRepository(e.g.BitbucketCloudorBitbucketServer)).
- "[Cloning a repository from GitHub to GitHub Desktop](https://help.github.com/desktop-classic/guides/contributing/cloning-a-repository-from-github-to-github-desktop/)"

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/desktop/open-in-desktop-button.png]

That is because those buttons are links using a protocol (like the [`x-github-client` protocol](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/2558#issuecomment-325228912)) which [register an action (here: "opening GitHub Desktop")](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/3215#note_82936568)

> This is a protocol:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\x-github-client]
> @="URL:x-github-client"
> "URL Protocol"=""
> ```
>
> This is a protocol handler:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\someapp\shell]
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\someapp\shell\open]
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\someapp\shell\open\command]
> @=someapp.exe \"%1\"
> ```
>
> This is what associates an app to a protocol:
>
> ```
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SomeApp\Capabilities\UrlAssociations]
> "x-github-client"="someapp"
> ```